# A holomorhic function $f $ in the unit disc such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}f(z)$ does not exist

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in the open unit disc such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}f(z)$ does not exist. Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ be the Taylor sereis expansion of $f$ about $z=0$ and $R$ be its radius of convergence.Then

$(1)R=0$

$(2)0\lt R \lt 1$

$(3)R=1$

$(4)R\gt 1$

My thoughts or rather questions..

Can I say that $z=1$ is an essential singularity taking in concern that the limit there does not exist?

Again due to non-existence of limit  at $1$, it's clear $R\le 1$ but how do I exactly determine the radius of convergence of the Taylor series about $0$?

Please help me out .A good hint can be enough for me. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what does "holomorphic function in the open unit disc" tell you about $R$?

Comment: I think it says $R\le 1$.

Comment: think more (hint: if $R=2/3$ say can $f$ be holomorphic on the full circle $|z|=2/3$?)

Comment: I think you are  pointing at the fact that if the  radius of convergence  of a taylor series expansion is $R$ then there must be a singularity at the boundary implying in this question that $R$  must be $1$. Please rectify me sir, if I have misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Correct- $f$ holomorphic on the unit disc means radius at zero is at least $1$; the condition with $z\to 1$ gives  you $R=1$ as you noted